# How to perform multiple joins onto a table and then join resulting table onto multiple columns into another table

Tags: mysql, join

```
|  family_id  |  parent_id_1  |  parent_id_2  | 
-----------------------------------------------
|     1234    |      9999     |      9567     | 
-----------------------------------------------


|  person_id|    address_id |    name    |    job _id    |    
-----------------------------------------------------------
|   1234    |   3           |   ABCD     |    5          |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|   9999    |   4           |   ABCD     |    3          | 
-----------------------------------------------------------


|  job_id  |  title |  start_date | 
-----------------------------------------------
|     3    |    asdf|     3-2-2001| 
-----------------------------------------------

|  address_id  |  street |  zip    | 
-----------------------------------------------
|     3        | 1 main  |   11234 | 
-----------------------------------------------
```

I have copy and pasted a database schema from a similar question and made some minor modifications. In mysql I have several tables: Family, Person, Address, Job. Family has two columns that reference a person. A person has a column that references an Address, and one column that references a job. I would like query a family so that I can see both persons with their respective jobs and addresses. What is the correct way to accomplish that?

Comment: Are we actually talking about families or is that a stand-in for your actual problem?

Comment: its just a stand in because I copied and pasted

Comment: Ok, because that would be a really bad way to *actually* model families.  Do you want your output on one row or multiple rows?

Comment: I am not sure how it would be displayed on multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

You have would have to join twice:

```
SELECT
  fam.family_id
 ,fam.parent_id_1
 ,parent1.address_id AS parent_1_address_id
 ,parent1.name AS parent_1_name
 ,parent1.job_id AS parent_1_job_id
 ,fam.parent_id_2
 ,parent2.address_id AS parent_2_address_id
 ,parent2.name AS parent_2_name
 ,parent2.job_id AS parent_2_job_id
FROM
  family fam
LEFT JOIN
  person parent1
    ON parent1.person_id = fam.parent_id_1
LEFT JOIN
  person parent2
    ON parent2.person_id = fam.parent_id_2
LEFT JOIN
  job job1
    ON parent1.job_id = job1.job_id
<... over and over ... >
```

You can use a common table expression to wrap some of the identical code together, but it's the same steps ultimately:

```
WITH person_detail AS
(
  SELECT
    person.person_id
   ,person.name
   ,<job columns>
   ,<address columns>
  FROM
    person person
  LEFT JOIN
    job job
      ON job.job_id = person.job_id
  LEFT JOIN
    address address
     ON address.address_id = person.address_id
)
SELECT
  fam.family_id
 ,fam.parent_id_1
 ,<parent_1 columns>
 ,fam.parent_id_2
 ,<parent_2 columns>
FROM
  family fam
LEFT JOIN
  person_detail parent1
    ON parent1.person_id = fam.parent_id_1
LEFT JOIN
  person_detail parent2
    ON parent2.person_id = fam.parent_id_2
```

Comment: this works great, but it doesnt join the jobs and addresses onto the job_id and address_id columsn for each person

Comment: You don't have those listed in your question so I have no idea what columns you'd be adding or why.

Comment: to clarify, i always have to enumerate the exact columns I want to select along with their table aliases to prevent ambiguity, is that right? Also, is the common table expression query more efficient? And lastly, in your first example, would I have to left join job and address each twice as well?

Comment: 1. Yes, it is a good idea to include a reasonable table alias when you list the columns so it's easy to discern a column's source.  2. The CTE is less code, but depending on a few factors it could be slower. 3. Yes, if you choose the first method you would need join twice for each table of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Parentheses are allowed:

```
FROM ( a JOIN b ON ... )
JOIN ( c JOIN d ON ... ) ON ...
```

(etc)

This can be especially useful when using `RIGHT JOIN` or `LEFT JOIN` -- it will help clarify your intention without having to figure out the "precedence" rules.